# CSS Media Queries is not used when visiting the site from my mobile?

Tags: css, http, mobile, media-queries

I am using CSS Media Queries on my ASP.NET MVC webpage and I can see that when I make the browser smaller in Windows the CSS Media Queries will kick in.

But when visiting the webpage from my Phone (HTC Titan(Windows Phone)) the page will be shown only on the regular desktop version(not CSS Media Queries)?

Why?

The webpage is [www.biss.se](http://www.biss.se)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple explanation would be that the browser on your phone doesn't support them (yet).

Comment: wouldn't be sure if that's the issue..looking at the HTC Titan specs says it runs on 7.5 Mango, so it should have ie9 capable browsing - media queries should be working on them